# Resize a UIView inside a stackview

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview, window-resize

I need help to accomplish this:

1. Its a group of 3 photos. The first photo is the button screen before the click, the second photo is the screen after the click and the third photo is the way i've designed in the IB using stackview
   [image: screenshot]

I've being trying to create this and this is the result i've got so far. I still haven't created anything as the **After button click** image shows because of this:

1. My Result now

   [image: Screenshot]

As you can see in the gif when i press the button, the **UIView height constraint.constant** is set to a higher value and the UIView get higher. All i want is the stripped background to get higher as well.

This is the way the view is disposed in IB.

And finally, this is the way i've coded

---

```
    class LetterScreenViewController: UIViewController, ResizeWordViewDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var youTubeView: YouTubeView!
    @IBOutlet weak var phonemeView: PhonemeView!
    @IBOutlet weak var wordView: WordView!
    
    var letterPresenter: LetterPresenter?
    
    @IBOutlet weak var heightWordViewConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        delegateWordObj()
        if let presenter = letterPresenter {
            presenter.setupView()
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func dismissLetter(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    func delegateWordObj() {
        wordView.resizeWordViewDelegate = self
    }
    func didPressButton() {
        if heightWordViewConstraint.constant <= 0 {
            heightWordViewConstraint.constant = 30
        }else{
            heightWordViewConstraint.constant = 0
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
import UIKit
protocol ResizeWordViewDelegate {
    func didPressButton()
}
class WordView: UIView {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var backgroundListras: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var WordView: UIView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var showWordButton: UIButton!
    
    var resizeWordViewDelegate: ResizeWordViewDelegate!
        
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        xibInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        xibInit()
    }
    
    
    func xibInit() {
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("WordView", owner: self, options: nil)
        addSubview(WordView)
        WordView.frame = self.bounds
        WordView.round(corners: [.topLeft,.topRight], radius: 120)
        WordView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
    }
    
    @IBAction func showWordButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
        resizeWordViewDelegate.didPressButton()
        self.frame.size = CGSize(width: 375, height: 200)
        self.backgroundListras.frame.size = CGSize(width: 375, height: 200)
    }

}
```

I want to know a way to resize this UIView with all the content in it. After finding a solution to increase the height i'll be able to put all the others components shown when **i press the button**.

Comment: @MKR Hi, MKR. I've tried to: change the UIView size by code in the UIViewController, change the UIView size by code in the UIView own class, change the constraint.constant to a higher value and all these things I have done so far result in the same event as the gif link shows. The UIView get bigger but all the content stay at the same size even if I force a higher value to the stripes background height it change the value but doesn't change anything in the visual height in the simulator. Check this link https://imgur.com/a/eG43i. It shows that last thing i said.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your goal is to create something like this:

[image]

All I had to do was change the height of the constraint programmatically

Check the solution in the project below:

https://gitlab.com/DanielLimaDF/ResizeTest.git

Important: Beware of addSubview, it can remove constraints from a View if the constraints were created before calling addSubview

Comment: Ow! Thanks Daniel Lima. This is the effect i need to replicate!